# Flexbox and CSS Postions

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

Is it a good practice to use CSS positions with Flexbox or we should avoid it? A senior dev once told me that although we can use position, width, and height with flexbox, but we should not use it.

Is it fine or considered bad practice?

The position could be any position.

Comment: what? more than fine! just because you use flex box doesn't mean you should avoid all your other tools.. Yes I get what he's saying that dimensional properties override flexbox properties like flex-basis/-grow/-shrink etc. But that's when you can achieve some great results in UI/UX developement.

Comment: You should have asked the dev for his/her rationale. "Why should we not use it?"